# Search Query Not Handling Large Number of Users

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

We have an asp.net-core website which handles users search as follows:

```
    public async Task<ICollection<UserSearchResult>> SearchForUser(string name, int page)
    {
        return await db.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.Name.Contains(name) && !u.Deleted && u.AppearInSearch)
                                        .OrderByDescending(u => u.Verified)
                                        .Skip(page * recordsInPage)
                                        .Take(recordsInPage)
                                        .Select(u => new UserSearchResult()
                                        {
                                            Name = u.Name,
                                            Verified = u.Verified,
                                            PhotoURL = u.PhotoURL,
                                            UserID = u.Id,
                                            Subdomain = u.Subdomain
                                        }).ToListAsync();
    }
```

The query translates to something similar to the following:

```
SELECT [t].[Name], [t].[Verified], [t].[PhotoURL], [t].[Id], [t].[Subdomain]  FROM (SELECT [u0].*      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u0]      WHERE (((CHARINDEX('khaled', [u0].[Name]) > 0) OR ('khaled' = N'')) AND ([u0].[Deleted] = 0)) AND ([u0].[AppearInSearch] = 1)      ORDER BY [u0].[Verified] DESC      OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY  ) AS [t]
```

In Client-Side we use typeahead and bloodhound as follows:

```
    engine = new Bloodhound({
        identify: function (user) {
            return user.UserID;
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        dupDetector: function (a, b) { return a.UserID === b.UserID; },
        remote: {
            cache: false,
            url: '/account/Search?name=%QUERY&page=0',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });
```

and we configure typeahead as follows:

```
    $('#demo-input').typeahead(
    {
        hint: $('.Typeahead-hint'),
        menu: $('.Typeahead-menu'),
        minLength: 3,
        classNames:
        {
            open: 'is-open',
            empty: 'is-empty',
            cursor: 'is-active',
            suggestion: 'Typeahead-suggestion',
            selectable: 'Typeahead-selectable'
        }
    },
    {
        source: engineWithDefaults,
        displayKey: 'name',
        templates:
        {
            suggestion: template,
            empty: empty,
            footer: all
        },
        limit: 5
    })
```

The search works just find on localhost and the query runs great as a sql query.
I have also created an index on Verified and cut the speed to 1 second or less.

Our website has millions of registered users and the problem is that as soon as we make search available for all users the DTU percentage on Azure goes to 100% and the queries timeout.
We also have a redis cache to speed-up similar queries but this didn't help us with this issue.

Your support is appreciated :)

Comment: you can also use Full text search

Comment: @TheGameiswar can you please explain further? perhaps add it as an answer?

Comment: please check here,you need to use full text search for like based queries,we have a learning app for which we use the same to present results based on partial strings entered by users:https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Comment: @TheGameiswar this is not a like-based query, please check SQL query above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely to be `u.Name.Contains(name)` i.e. `CHARINDEX('khaled', [u0].[Name]) > 0` which will have to scan the entire table or, at best, the index.  That will be slow and there's not much you can do about it.

If you have a large bias to `deleted` or `appearInSearch` you might be able to use a conditional index but these types of searches are notoriously slow.  You will need some special constructs to make this work.

Comment: I see... but how are other sites able to achieve this with an even larger load as I have the website working without problems for a low load but I need a solution to implement on this. Thanks

Comment: If you can match just on the start of the name then you can try indexing `name` and using `StartsWith` which will translate to `NAME LIKE 'Khaled%'`.  More than that and you'll need to look at non-SQL solutions or create all the various parts of the username, kha, hal, ale etc. and search on that.  It gets hard and complicated pretty quickly.

Comment: I can't use startsWith only in my case. I'm afraid that the other way you explained will even cause more calls to the database. Thanks.

Comment: Not more calls, more rows in the database.  You have to build many rows for each name that goes in.  Some other DBs, such as ElasticSearch can do this kind of thing more naturally than SQL Server and similar.  If this is a real need over millions of user names then consider using it for this part of your problem.